# kernel driver: How get correct content of each variable in a struct?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio, driver, kernel-mode

I have the following code involving a `struct` including pointer variables and I am not able to retrieve the correct contents of each variable.

Someone can help me please?

```
struct MyData
    {
        ULONG Value[3];
        wchar_t *Str1;
        int Str1Len;
        wchar_t *Str2;
        int Str2Len;
    };

    // In the driver, on method that receives commands i have following:

    struct MyData *pData = (struct MyData*) Irp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer; 

    DbgPrint("0x%x \n 0x%x \n 0x%x \n %s \n %d \n %s \n %d", &pData->Value[0], &pData->Value[1], &pData->Value[2], &pData.Str1, &pData->Str1Len, &pData->Str2, &pData->Str2Len);
```

Comment: You can't just pass a pointer from user mode to kernel mode.  Try using a character array instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DbgPrint` is called very much like `printf` is called, so you should pass the values, not the *address* of the values. So

```
DbgPrint("0x%x \n 0x%x \n 0x%x \n %s \n %d \n %s \n %d", &pData->Value[0], // etc...
```

should be

```
DbgPrint("0x%x \n 0x%x \n 0x%x \n %s \n %d \n %s \n %d", pData->Value[0],  // etc...
```

Comment: Moreover, the format specifiers do not all match the data types.

Comment: your suggestion worked to `ULONG` type, but not worked to `wchar_t*`.

Comment: eg: if i send: `\\SystemRoot\\System32\\win32k.sys`, not works. Receives only one "\" on each variable `wchar_t*`

Comment: See my first comment. Even the `%x` for `ULONG` is incorrect, it should be `%lx`. Use `%S` for wide strings (I think).

Comment: i'm sending `PWideChar` (Delphi) for each `wchar_t*` on driver.

Comment: still no tested, but probably the solution to `wchar_t*` is capture as index. Eg: `pData->Str1[3]` ... etc, i had forgot, sorry.